# How to copy clipboard value into javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am checking possibilities of nut.js and I've encountered an issue. Program is able to copy value off website/document and I would like to keep copied value in js variable for comparison. Is that possible with nut.js or do I need some different tool to achieve that?

```
var paste = async() => {
let time = navigator.clipboard.writeText()
console.log(time) 
}
```

Above code throws an error:
"(node:13432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: navigator is not defined"

That's probably because navigator works in browser only. I need to access current clipboard value from my PC.

Thanks

Comment: Is this running in the browser?

Comment: No. It is something like robot.js which takes control of your mouse, keyboard and screen to automate certain tasks. I want to copy content off website tho

Comment: navigator isn't standard JavaScript and is a browser only API. You'll have to figure out a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using nut.js

```
var clipboardData = async() => {
let data = await clipboard.paste()
console.log(data)
}
```

Issue can be closed